# Object missing data when retrieved from Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have an `Attack` object.

**Attack.java**

```
public class Attack implements Parcelable {
    private String pushId, website;
    private int networkType;
    private long timeMillis;
    private Map<String, String> hostInfo = new HashMap<>();
    private List<String> botIds = new ArrayList<>(); 

    public Attack() {
    }

    public Map<String, String> getHostInfo() {
        return hostInfo;
    }

    // getters/setters
}
```

**The problem**

I store an `Attack` at Firebase Database but when I am trying to retrieve them, its `attack.getHostInfo()` has one value instead of 4 as shown in the screenshot bellow.

Here is a screenshot of that instance from the console:

[image]

**How listener is attached**

I don't attach a `ChildEventListener` to an activity directly, but through a module called [`AttackRepository`](https://github.com/tomasmichael995/DDoSDroid/blob/mvc_model/app/src/main/java/gr/kalymnos/sk3m3l10/ddosdroid/mvc_model/repository/AttackRepository.java). An activity can use this class to *upload / update / delete* an`Attack` or to listen when an `Attack` was *uploaded / updated / deleted*.

**Implementation of** `AttackRepository` **using Firebase**

That's the [`FirebaseRepository` class](https://github.com/tomasmichael995/DDoSDroid/blob/mvc_model/app/src/main/java/gr/kalymnos/sk3m3l10/ddosdroid/mvc_model/repository/FirebaseRepository.java). Here is where the listener is attached:

```
public void startListenForChanges() {
    allAttacksRef.addChildEventListener(this);
}
```

So a stakeholder, a `Fragment` in my case, calls the above method and get's informed through `AttackRepository` when an `Attack` is uploaded, etc.

And, lastly, here is where how the stakeholder get's the data.

```
public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    Attack attack = dataSnapshot.getValue(Attack.class);
    repositoryListener.onAttackUpload(attack);
}
```

My fragment need to use the values of `Attack.hostInfo` but the other three are missing!

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code in `Attack` to the minimum that is needed to reproduce the problem. Then please expand the rest of your code to also show how and where you attach your listener to the database.

Comment: `attack.hostInfo` is null?

Comment: And please also show us how you check the `hostInfo` property that you it's `null`. Please also responde with @

Comment: Instead of a HashMap you could declare each String in your POJO with the names inside hostInfo, and then access them one by one

Comment: I don't know exactly how Firebase handles serialization, but I do notice that you don't have either a constructor parameter or a setter for `hostInfo`. Are you certain that `hostInfo` is *null* rather than *empty*?

Comment: Sorry folks, had to leave the house, I've edited the question @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: @AlexMamo My mistake, `attack.hostInfo` is not null, but instead of having 4 values it includes only one!

Comment: Now please also show how you initialize `allAttacksRef`. Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as building one interactively is highly inefficient..

Comment: `FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        allAttacksRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child(NODE_ATTACKS);` @FrankvanPuffelen where NODE_ATTACKS is "attacks", as in the screenshot

Comment: To save time the `Attack` that is retrieved is the correct one, with the exception of the `hostInfo` where 3 values are missing @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem. See my "answer" below for what I did, as there's no way to fit it into a comment. Also note: if you still can't get it to work, post something that is equally self-contained as your question. Right now, there are just too many parts, and we can't simply take what you've shared and reproduce the problem with it, which makes it hard to help. [Creating an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) typically involves restarting from scratch, and adding minimal bits until you are able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You're right and I appreciate the help anyway @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce your problem. Here's the minimal, standalone code that I've tried:

```
final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("54752112");
ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Attack attack = dataSnapshot.getValue(Attack.class);
        Log.i("Attack", attack.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildKey) { }
    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { }
    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildKey) { }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

The only thing I changed about your original `Attack` class is that I added a `toString()` to it to print the properties:

```
 @Override
 public String toString() {
     return "{ pushId: '"+pushId+"', website: '"+website+"', networkType: "+networkType+
            ", timeMillis: "+timeMillis+", hostInfo: "+hostInfo.toString()+" }";
 }
```

And here's the JSON I used ([live link](http://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/54752112.json?print=pretty)):

```
{
  "-LZ0zS9LBuBxuW695B_i" : {
    "hostInfo" : {
      "extra_attack_host_uuid" : "cUgi890-Yrg",
      "extra_device_name" : "[Phone] Galaxy A3 (2016)",
      "extra_local_port" : "48790",
      "extra_mac_address" : "aa:81:95:c5:69:94"
    },
    "networkType" : 1,
    "pushId" : "-LZ0zS9LBuBxuW695B_i",
    "timeMillis" : 1550516609582,
    "website" : "http://www.sport24.gr"
  }
}
```

When I run the above, it prints:

> I/Attack: { pushId: '-LZ0zS9LBuBxuW695B_i', website: 'http://www.sport24.gr', networkType: 1, timeMillis: 1550516609582, hostInfo: {extra_mac_address=aa:81:95:c5:69:94, extra_device_name=[Phone] Galaxy A3 (2016), extra_local_port=48790, extra_attack_host_uuid=cUgi890-Yrg} }

Comment: Found the bug and I feel the need to inform you. The problem was a silent update of the specific data between upload and download.